# PHP add unique User array to newly created array while iterating over Episode authors object

Tags: php

Hi i am iterating over Episodes getting array of authors and inside this loop i want to gather information about each author. But there is problem, i just need the information about each author once.

This is my approatch, but wrong. and the code i am trying to make. Please help. I tried also in_array, and array_filter but without success.

```
$presentUsers = [];
    $pUi = 0;
    if ($isAuthor == true){
        if ($project->getType() == 1) {
            $episodes = $project->getComic()->getComicEpisodes();

            foreach ($episodes as $comicEpisode) {
                foreach ($comicEpisode->getProject()->getAccount() as $author) {
                    if ($author->getUser()->getId() == $this->getUser()->getId()) {
                        $comicEpisode->setIsMine(true);
                        $comicEpisode->setRevenue($author->getRevenue());
                        $comicEpisode->setIncome($author->getIncome());
                    }

                    if (empty($presentUsers)){
                        $presentUsers[$pUi]['Id'] = $author->getUser()->getId();
                        $presentUsers[$pUi]['Username'] = $author->getUser()->getUsername();
                        $presentUsers[$pUi]['FirstName'] = $author->getUser()->getFirstName();
                        $presentUsers[$pUi]['LastName'] = $author->getUser()->getLastName();
                        $presentUsers[$pUi]['VisibleName'] = $author->getUser()->getVisibleName();
                        $presentUsers[$pUi]['AvatarFileName'] = $author->getUser()->getAvatarFileName();
                        $presentUsers[$pUi]['Occupation'] = $author->getUser()->getOccupation();
                        $presentUsers[$pUi]['LastOnline'] = $author->getUser()->getLastOnline();
                        $pUi++;
                    }else{
                        if (!in_array($presentUsers, ['Id'=>$author->getUser()->getId()]))
                        {
                            $presentUsers[$pUi]['Id'] = $author->getUser()->getId();
                            $presentUsers[$pUi]['Username'] = $author->getUser()->getUsername();
                            $presentUsers[$pUi]['FirstName'] = $author->getUser()->getFirstName();
                            $presentUsers[$pUi]['LastName'] = $author->getUser()->getLastName();
                            $presentUsers[$pUi]['VisibleName'] = $author->getUser()->getVisibleName();
                            $presentUsers[$pUi]['AvatarFileName'] = $author->getUser()->getAvatarFileName();
                            $presentUsers[$pUi]['Occupation'] = $author->getUser()->getOccupation();
                            $presentUsers[$pUi]['LastOnline'] = $author->getUser()->getLastOnline();
                            $pUi++;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }else{
        die('You are not the author of this project.');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay i done it like this

```
if (empty($presentUsers)){
                        $presentUsers[$pUi]['Id'] = $author->getUser()->getId();
                        $presentUsers[$pUi]['Username'] = $author->getUser()->getUsername();
                        $presentUsers[$pUi]['FirstName'] = $author->getUser()->getFirstName();
                        $presentUsers[$pUi]['LastName'] = $author->getUser()->getLastName();
                        $presentUsers[$pUi]['VisibleName'] = $author->getUser()->getVisibleName();
                        $presentUsers[$pUi]['AvatarFileName'] = $author->getUser()->getAvatarFileName();
                        $presentUsers[$pUi]['Occupation'] = $author->getUser()->getOccupation();
                        $presentUsers[$pUi]['LastOnline'] = $author->getUser()->getLastOnline();
                        $pUi++;
                    }else{
                        $found = 0;
                        foreach ($presentUsers as $presentUser){
                            if ($presentUser['Id'] == $author->getUser()->getId()){
                                $found = 1;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if ($found != 1)
                        {
                            $presentUsers[$pUi]['Id'] = $author->getUser()->getId();
                            $presentUsers[$pUi]['Username'] = $author->getUser()->getUsername();
                            $presentUsers[$pUi]['FirstName'] = $author->getUser()->getFirstName();
                            $presentUsers[$pUi]['LastName'] = $author->getUser()->getLastName();
                            $presentUsers[$pUi]['VisibleName'] = $author->getUser()->getVisibleName();
                            $presentUsers[$pUi]['AvatarFileName'] = $author->getUser()->getAvatarFileName();
                            $presentUsers[$pUi]['Occupation'] = $author->getUser()->getOccupation();
                            $presentUsers[$pUi]['LastOnline'] = $author->getUser()->getLastOnline();
                            $pUi++;
                        }
                    }
```